# Implement VS Code tsx (typescript react) user defined snippet using conditional regular expression substitution

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, react-typescript, tsx, vscode-snippets

I am trying to write a simple tsx function component snippet.
The snippet should look like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react'

interface HomeProps {
  $2
}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ $2 }) => {
  return <div>Home</div>
}

export default Home
```

Let's focus on $2. All I want to achieve is that when user finish the interface, then we should get some processed $2 in function props. Something like this:

```js
interface HomeProps{
  age: number
  name: string
}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ age, name }) => {
...
```

Here is my snippet code in JSON:

```
        "TypeScript React Function Component with Props": {
            "prefix": "trfp",
            "body": [
                "import * as React from 'react'",
                "",
                "interface ${1:${TM_FILENAME/(^.)(.*)\\..*/${1:/upcase}$2/}}Props {",
                "\t$2",
                "}"
                "",
                "const $1: React.FC<$1Props> = ({ ${2/(.*):.*/$1, /g} }) => {",
                "\treturn $3",
                "}",
                "",
                "export default $1"
            ],
            "description": "TypeScript React Function Component with Props",
        }
```

I want some help with this line:
`"const $1: React.FC<$1Props> = ({ ${2/(.*):.*/$1, /g} }) => {",`

With this line I can get the result like:

```js
interface HomeProps{
  age: number
  name: string
}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ age, 
name, }) => {
...
```

1. How can I join groups in one line?
2. How can I join them with comma but without trailing comma?

It takes me hours but I still can't figure it out. Can someone help?

Here is my goal:

```js
interface HomeProps{
  age: number
  name: string
}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ age, name }) => {
...
```

**Update**

I try some conditional regex to change the line to
`"const $1: React.FC<$1Props> = ({ ${2/(.*):.*(\r?\n)/$1${2:+, }/g} }) => {",`

Now I can get

```js
interface HomeProps {
  key: string
  val: number
}

const Index: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ key, val: number }) => {
  return
}
```

I also try ternary condition as described in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets.
`${2:?, :}`, which means or what I want if group 2 (next line) exists, replace it with `,` , otherwise replace with a empty string.
However I also got the wrong result:

```js
interface HomeProps {
  key: string
  val: number
}

const Index: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ key${2:?, :}val: number }) => {
  return 
}
```

It seems like I am getting close to the answer but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```json
"TypeScript React Function Component with Props": {
    "prefix": "trfp",
    "body": [
            "import * as React from 'react'",
            "",
            "interface ${1:${TM_FILENAME/(^.)(.*)\\..*/${1:/upcase}$2/}}Props {",
            "\t$2",
            "}"
            "",
                     // note double-backslashes \\?
            "const $1: React.FC<$1Props> = ({ ${2/(.*?)\\??:\\s*.*(\n?)/$1${2:+, }/g} }) => {",
                     // this also works: [?]?
            // "const $1: React.FC<$1Props> = ({ ${2/(.*?)[?]?:\\s*.*(\n?)/$1${2:+, }/g} }) => {",
            "\treturn $3",
            "}",
            "",
            "export default $1"
    ],
    "description": "TypeScript React Function Component with Props",
}
```

Here is where I made changes:

```
${2/(.*):\\s*.*(\n?)/$1${2:+, }/g}
```

First, you didn't seem to be accounting for the space after the `:`, so I added `\\s*` to the regex (`\s` must be double-escaped.

Second, you need to match (but won't use) the newline between your entries.  But your last entry won't have a newline so it is optionally captured `(\n?)`.

Third, that optional new line is captured in group 2.  After the last entry (like your `name: string`) is added and you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> you do not want another `,`  added to the end.  That should only be added if there is another entry - in which case there would be a newline between them.

So `${2:+, }` is a conditional IF.   If there is a capture group 2, add `,` .  If there is no group 2, nothing is added after group 1.

---

I don't know if it is required but the snippet also works if there are commas after the entries, like

```json
  age: number,           // space after the :, comma at end
  name?:string,           // no space after :, comma. Optional ? removed  
  true?     : boolean     // lots of space after :, no trailing comma
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the question mark in optional type?
I try to transform `str?: string` to `str` as argument in my function. Therefore, I tried `${2/(.*)\??:\\s*.*(\n?)/$1${2:+, }/g` and `${2/([^\?]*)\??:\\s*.*(\n?)/$1${2:+, }/g`, but both of them don't work.

Comment: @TimLu This should work `(.*?)\\??:\\s*.*(\n?)` so you just needed to double-backslash the optional `\\?`.  I edited the answer to show that and another way to do it.